# Can I use a class type parameter inside an annotation?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

Think about the given scenario:

```
public @interface SomeThirdAnnotation {
    Class<? extends Something> value();
}

@SomeThirdAnnotation(T)
public abstract class MyClass<T extends Something> {
    // my code
}
```

Can this be possible in JAVA?

Is there any way to use a class type parameter inside annotations, because doing it will drastically remove code from the abstract class children.

Thank you very much for those who try to help me.

Comment: No.  Only constants like `Something.class` may be annotation values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Annotations cannot be generic or specify a throws clause. Annotations must return: an enum, primitive type or an annotation, String, or Class object. They can also return an array of these types." source: [here](https://blog.usejournal.com/how-much-do-you-actually-know-about-annotations-in-java-b999e100b929)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. If anyone answer in 7 days, I'll vote up and accept your answer @vc73.